# Multiple Predicates to group collection to hashmap

Tags: java-8, java-stream, predicate

I have a list of Objects as below -

```
List<Transaction>
```

where the Transaction Object will look like

```
Transaction {

    String Status;
}

Status <A,B,C,D,E,F,G...>

If Status in (A,B,C)->Success
If Status in (D,E,F)->Failure
If Status in (G,H...)->Pending
```

Individual Predicates for identifying each status transaction are defined.

Expected output would be a hashmap with the Success/Failure/Rejected text as key and collective count of these statuses as value

```
HashMap<String, Integer> ->
    {
        "Success": 1,
        "Failure":2,
        "Pending":2
    }
```

I am unable to proceed how to do this in a single execution. Right now, I get the counts separately. Can anyone please assist with the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may first declare an enum like this to represent the 3 states that you are interested in.

```
public enum TxStatus {
    Success, Failure, Pending;
}
```

Then write a method in `Transaction` to transform the `String` literal value into a real status value that you expect. Here's a one such implementation.

```
public class Transaction {
    private final String status;
    private Pattern SUCCESS_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[ABC]");
    private Pattern FAILURE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[DEF]");
    private Pattern PENDING_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[GHI]");

    public Transaction(String status) {
        super();
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public TxStatus interpretStatus() {
        if (SUCCESS_PATTERN.matcher(status).matches()) {
            return TxStatus.Success;
        }
        if (FAILURE_PATTERN.matcher(status).matches()) {
            return TxStatus.Failure;
        }
        if (PENDING_PATTERN.matcher(status).matches()) {
            return TxStatus.Pending;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid status value.");
    }
}
```

Finally your client code should look something like this,

```
Map<String, Long> txStatusToCountMap = txs.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(tx -> tx.interpretStatus().toString(), 
        Collectors.counting()));
```